# Recommended printer for Flash PrintJob() (Name Badges)

Tags: flash, printing

A client needs a standard consumer color printer for printing name badges from my flash app.  Last time we used the app, I couldn't do any pre-testing of their computer and printer beforehand.  So, of course, the margins were completely wrong when the time came to print.  Ideally, I'll have the flash app's bugs worked out for the next run, but for safety's sake does anyone know of a printer that has good controls for custom margins and offsets, in case some minor adjustments are needed?

Answer (score 0):

A less than eloquent fix that seemed to do the trick was to add some text fields that nudged the movieclip in the print job along the X and Y axes.  This worked fine since it was an application that would only be used a handful of times and could be set for the duration of the event.